# can't delete pages

Tags: nodes

When I try to delete an article or page, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: pid in simple_access_node_delete() (line 263 of /home5/piconepr/public_html/isip/drupal/sites/all/modules/simple_access/simple_access.module).
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pid' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM {simple_access_node} WHERE (pid IS NULL ) ; Array ( ) in simple_access_node_delete() (line 264 of /home5/piconepr/public_html/isip/drupal/sites/all/modules/simple_access/simple_access.module).
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

This is pretty bad because I can no longer delete articles from my main page.

Is there an easy way to make this error go away. I am not an SQL programmer and I hate to think I will have to go into the database and muck around with it.

Comment: try to disable the simple access module and then delete the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the cache. To do so, go to

Home » Administration » Configuration » Development

And then click 'Clear all caches' button.

Make sure that the user who attempt to delete the page has permission to do so.